# Anylogic move an agent in free space, with another agent who needs an agent to drive it

Tags: anylogic, agent, transport

This should be farely simple - maybe my brain is just too tired..
I have a pallet in a fixed location that needs to move to another location.  (Forklift in free space works great - seize transporter, then transport it and release transporter).  But no forklifts allowed in this area.  OK, so we use a pallet-trolley.  But it can't move on its own, it needs an operator - and he is smoking outside.  So simple question, how do we get the operator to move to the trolley, attach the trolley and then move to the pallet and move it to where it needs to go.  Afterwards operator returns the trolley to where it needs to be and then can go on his way doing whatever he likes?

I sort of get the feeling the operator needs to be a free space moving transporter - then I can just seize him, move and release him, exactly as with the forklift - but somehow I need the operator to first move to and attach the trolley when he is called - its like the solution is staring me right in the eyes I just can't see it..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to add a preparation workflow for the pallet-trolley. Before the trolley is seized, it should seize an operator.

Check this:
https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/processmodeling/resourcetaskstart.html?cp=2_0_1_18

Comment: Thank you Emile.  This will not work with the transporter idea (fleet of free-space transporters, for the "seize transporter" block does not have the resource preparation link), however a bit of extra research has shown that if using resources (instead of transporters) do do the movement manually - seize resource, then for example pickup and dropoff, then this works perfectly.  Thank you for pointing me in right direction!